# Ghost image issues with ffmpeg -filter_complex displace

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing

I've (almost) been able to apply a displacement based on 2 animated gaussian noise videos, but I'm having issues with a ghost image. [A picture is worth a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64uzO.png).

Here you have a script to replicate the issue:

```
ffmpeg -y -t 2 -f lavfi -i color=c=blue:s=160x120 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt rgb24 00_empty.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i 00_empty.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text=string1:y=h/2:x=w-t*w/2:fontcolor=white:fontsize=60" 01_text.mp4
ffmpeg -y -t 2 -f lavfi -i color=c=gray:s=160x120 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt rgb24 02_gray.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i 01_text.mp4 -i 02_gray.mp4 -i 02_gray.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2]displace=edge=mirror" 03_displaced_text.mp4
```

It creates a test video with a scrolling text and a gray dummy video. Then it applies a displacement based on the gray video. If I understand correctly, because the gray video is 100% gray, it should leave the video unchanged (or maybe displace everything by a fixed ammount of pixels), but [it creates a "shadow"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLZe9.png). I tried with 3 different pixel formats (yuv420p, yuv444p, rgb24) because I found this question on stackoverflow talking about that:

- [Why are Cb and Cr planes displaced differently from lum by the displace complex filter in ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43820170)

ffmpeg version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev

Any idea will be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: the shadow _is_ the fixed displacement, isn't it? oh, you mean the luma and chroma planes are displaced differently? that shouldn't have left the "white" text intact...

Comment: Shouldn't a displacement "displace the whole image"? I don't get why it displaces it leaving a visible version of the non-displaced source.

I may not be understanding how "displace" works but, again, if I just diplace all the image by a fixed and constant ammount (a 100% gray video), shouldn't the result just be the original video shifted X pixels in some direction?

Comment: if each plane is displaced separately... in its own resolution, then this might happen. I have no idea what ffmpeg does here, nor did I inspect those filter expressions. basically... the question+answer you linked already discuss this. I don't see the point of this question.

Comment: >>  the question+answer you linked already discuss this. I don't see the point of this question.

As explained, I already tried with square pixel formats as suggested by the linked question and it still happens.

Comment: what does ffprobe say about the pixel format of your intermediate files?

Comment: With you444p and yuv420p seem consistent with the specified options: https://pastebin.com/raw/Eb3RMfws

With rgb24 I rrealized that I was getting a "Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'libx264', auto-selecting format 'yuv444p'" error when generatign 02_gray.mp4

But AFAIK you444p is a square pixel format.
Thanks.

Comment: yuv444 is good, no subsampling, but yuv420 means chroma subsampling. -- it's not really about square pixels but about the resolution of the chroma planes vs the luma plane. yuv420 chroma "pixels" are as square as the luma pixels, they're just twice as big

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So, if I understand correctly, with you444p it should displace chroma and luma planes the same amount, right?

Comment: it should, I would expect that too... if it doesn't then, something'd be *really* fishy. I'd recommend hopping on IRC (libera) and asking in #ffmpeg. there are some people there with great knowledge.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz FYI: Solution added as an asnwer (thanks to the help in another post)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: using `-pix_fmt rgb24` and adding `-c:v libx264rgb` to all commands fixes it:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -t 2 -f lavfi -i color=c=blue:s=160x120 -tune stillimage -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 00_empty.mp4
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i 00_empty.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text=string1:y=h/2:x=w-t*w/2:fontcolor=white:fontsize=60" -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 01_text.mp4
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -t 2 -f lavfi -i color=c=gray:s=160x120 -tune stillimage -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 02_gray.mp4
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i 01_text.mp4 -i 02_gray.mp4 -i 02_gray.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1][2]displace=edge=mirror" -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 03_displaced_text.mp4
```

Thanks to [poisondeathray's answer in a post at forum.videohelp.com](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/406269-%5BSOLVED%5D-Ghost-image-issues-with-ffmpeg-filter_complex-displace#post2661776):

> the real reason is the 8it RGB to YUV gray conversion for 02_gray.mp4 becomes YUV 126,128,128 (loss of accuracy from the 8bit conversion)
> https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_displace.c
> If you supply a true gray YUV 128,128,128 video it works ok too